# Qt5 exe not running in windows8

Tags: qt5

I have a qt application which was in `qt4.7` and I ported it to `qt5.0`. It is working fine if it is run from a `PC where qt5 is installed`. But it is *not running or not even giving any error message if it is run from a pc where qt is not installed* even though it has all the dlls in the same folder.

But if I install qt and try from the same folder the application will work without even setting the *environment variable*. In some questions i have seen people replied about adding the dlls and i have tried adding all the dlls specified by them. But nothing helped. Any body has an idea how to handle this.

Comment: Most likely a dll issue. Had similar problem a week ago, got it working using depends + F9.

Comment: Mati, I had run dependeny walker and it says one imported module does not have the export and one module is not found. but how can i identify the missing dll.

Comment: Is your app built with MinGW or VS?

Comment: Hi mati,we are using VS compiler

Comment: Can't help you out with VS. However, [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html) might be helpful. Use key F9 in Dependency Walker to find out the specific dlls and their (current) paths.

Answer (score 0):

Qt 5 introduced the use of some DLLs that are loaded at run-time (as opposed to launch-time). These DLLs can only be detected by Dependency Walker if you use the "profiling" feature, which is not on by default.

I'm assuming that you're using the precompiled package from the Qt Project website. The community found a silent dependency on libEGL.dll, and a less-silent dependency on qwindows.dll, which must be placed relative to your .exe with this folder structure:

```
app.exe
libEGL.dll
platforms\qwindows.dll
```

Also, see if you can find anything useful at http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28766) on [bugreports.qt-project.org](https://bugreports.qt-project.org). It can help.